# Problem with trying to wrap my head around hashmap and get code

Tags: java

So I am having trouble trying to wrap my head around this coding problem: Here are four questions that they want me to answer: 
How many times will 'getValue(…)' execute with the following inputs, and what will be the result?

(1) getValue("foo", 0);

(2) getValue("bar", 2);

(3) getValue("baz", 0);

(4) getValue("fubar", 1);

I know the first two answers:

1) will execute one time and return 1

2) will execute 1 time and return 3
But the last two problems (3,4) I don't understand. Can anyone help clarify what exactly this code is doing and hint to what the answers are?

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class myClass {

private Map<String,Integer> map;

public myClass() {

map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("foo", 1);

map.put("bar", 3);

}

public int getValue(String input, int numRetries) throws Exception {

try {

  return map.get(input);

}

catch (Exception e) {

  if (numRetries > 3) {

    throw e;

  }

  return getValue(input, numRetries + 1);

}

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The trick is going to be knowing what `HashMap.get()` does for an item not in the map.

Comment: Consider that a `Map` can only contain `Integer` values, but `getValue` needs to return `int`.

Comment: @John3136 Hello John, I do admit that was one issue that I was struggling hard about and getting research about. Not knowing what Hashmap.get() does when the item is not in the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as you rightly answered in (1) and (2) attempts to get a value from a HashMap given it's key.

The getValue() function is a recursive function, meaning it calls itself a number of times based on the 'numRetries' value

(3) the codes calls itself 4 times (where the numRetries progress from 0,1,2,3 before the '>3' clause becomes true and an Exception gets thrown)

(4) the codes calls itself 3 times (where the numRetries progress from 1,2,3 before the '>3' clause becomes true and an Exception gets thrown)

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I am starting to understand it. I think I just overthought the question way too hard! Haha.